# How to use "graythresh()" properly?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, threshold

I am using "graythresh()" to threshold and clean a picture after some process I make on it, and this function works perfectly, but some times when there is no data to threshold like the whole image is almost zeros (black) and there is no clear object to threshold in the image, this function makes rubbish process like spreading white points all over the image and gives useless data.
So how can I fix that or at least test the image before passing into this method to see if it has clear object to threshold or not?

```
x = graythresh(resaultImage);
b = im2bw(resaultImage,x);
```

Comment: Did you look at the second return value of [`graythresh`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html), the effectiveness metric `EM`?

Comment: you can also check the standard deviation of the image and if its less than some threshold don't use `graythresh` something like `if (std(im(:)) < my_thresh)` another measure you can use instead of standard deviation is entropy

Answer (score 0):

The graythresh function uses Otsu's method, which chooses the threshold to minimize the intraclass variance of the black and white pixels.
Its means that in every image graythresh obtain a "regular" threshold.

You can put a fixed threshold 
     `b = im2bw(resaultImage,x);` with  `0<x<1`
You can also count the connected components in the image and,if the number of connected components is 0,you take a fixed threshold and if the number of connected components is greater or equal to 1,you take the threshold with the graythresh function